# .NET Await doesn't hold execution as desired

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I wrote an extension for `ComboBox` to perform a query when user types something and set its `DataSource` with the result of this query, allowing user to choose within the results just before leaving the control:

```
Public NotInheritable Class QueryBoxEx

    Inherits ComboBox

    Public Event Query As EventHandler(Of QueryEventArgs)

    Protected Sub OnQuery(e As QueryEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Query(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnValidating(e As CancelEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnValidating(e)
        If SelectedIndex = -1 AndAlso Not (e.Cancel OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text)) Then
            Dim qe As New QueryEventArgs With {
                .Text = Text,
                .DataSource = DataSource,
                .DisplayMember = DisplayMember,
                .ValueMember = ValueMember}
            OnQuery(qe)
            If qe.Handled Then
                DisplayMember = qe.DisplayMember
                ValueMember = qe.ValueMember
                DataSource = qe.DataSource
                If Items.Count > 1 Then
                    e.Cancel = DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
                    If e.Cancel Then
                        DroppedDown = True
                        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Class QueryEventArgs

        Inherits EventArgs

        Public Property DataSource As DataTable

        Public Property DisplayMember As String

        Public Property Handled As Boolean

        Public Property Text As String

        Public Property ValueMember As String

    End Class

End Class
```

This is an example of the usage (`Function GetMyDataSource(query As String)` returns a `DataTable` object):

```
Private Sub QueryBoxEx1_SyncQuery(sender As Object, e As QueryBoxEx.QueryEventArgs) Handles QueryBoxEx1.Query
    Dim query = Utilities.Digits(e.Text)
    If Utilities.Validar.CPF(query) Then
        e.DataSource = GetMyDataSource(query)
        e.DisplayMember = "display"
        e.ValueMember = "pessoa_id"
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

It works as intended. However, since `GetMyDataSource()` can take some seconds to return, and I would like to release the UI thread, I tried this Async/Await implementation:

```
Private Async Sub QueryBoxEx1_AsyncQuery(sender As Object, e As QueryBoxEx.QueryEventArgs) Handles QueryBoxEx1.Query
    Dim query = Utilities.Digits(e.Text)
    If Utilities.Validar.CPF(query) Then
        e.DataSource = Await Task.Run(Function() GetMyDataSource(query))
        e.DisplayMember = "display"
        e.ValueMember = "pessoa_id"
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

But then it stops working. The flow returns immediately back to statements following event's raising, and thus `Datasource` isn't properly set; besides, the result of `GetMyDataSource()` is lost in-between.

Same problem with the following variation I also tried:

```
Private Async Sub QueryBoxEx1_AsyncQuery(sender As Object, e As QueryBoxEx.QueryEventArgs) Handles QueryBoxEx1.Query
    Dim query = Utilities.Digits(e.Text)
    If Utilities.Validar.CPF(query) Then
        Await Task.Run(
            Sub()
                e.DataSource = GetMyDataSource(query)
                e.DisplayMember = "display"
                e.ValueMember = "pessoa_id"
                e.Handled = True
            End Sub)
    End If
End Sub
```

So, any help or insight on how to wait for `GetMyDataSource()` without blocking the UI thread in this case is most welcome!

Comment: OnValidate->start thread()->fetchData()-> InvokeCallOnUiThread-> setDataSource()

Comment: looks like you are making multiple calls without waiting for the first one to finish. Blocking the UI thread makes it impossible for the user to be typing while you query the database. Even if you were to runs this on a separate thread you wouldn't get the result you want. Making your function async is good and await it is perfect. now what you need to do is block your app from making other calls to that function until it gets back from the previous call. Check if the flag is set to "true" before running the query then set the flag ex: QueryRunning=true when you get out QueryRunning=false

Comment: @Chillzy, `OnQuery()` isn't called as user types, but only when they're about to leave the control, inside overrided `OnValidating()` sub.

Comment: Can you make `GetMyDataSource` `async`?  That would solve the majority of your issue.  You would no longer need to use `Task.Run`, and you could `await` the `DataSource` directly.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, I'm not sure. `GetMyDataSource` wraps several operations that prepare an http request, execute it, parse several types of response and then create and populate a datatable which is finally returned. Since I never wrote an async method before, I don't know how should I tweak my existing code...

Comment: @VBobCat That makes it sounds like a prime candidate for an `async` function actually.  It could be tricky to convert, depending on how complex the logic is, and how many other things it is connected to, but waiting for http responses is one of the main use-cases for `asyc`.

Comment: Could you point me out some kind of tutorial or instructions to write async methods, or even better, convert existing ones? VB.NET examples are more welcome than C# ones, if they're available :-)

Comment: I confess I loathe these trigger-happy stealth downvoters who don't care commenting a single phrase to explain why then don't fancy a question... :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot await event handlers. Events are really just notifications that something else happened so that you can perform some task separate from the task that triggered the event.

It seems like you want to do this:

1. Do something
2. Raise event
3. Wait for event handler to finish
4. Do some more stuff

Step 3 is what you cannot do. The event model isn't designed for that.

So you have two options:

1. Don't use an event (just call another method normally instead of raising an event), or
2. Do the other stuff (the `DisplayMember = qe.DisplayMember`, etc.) inside the event handler

Here's an example of doing option 1, although not even using a separate method - you can make the `OnValidating` event `Async` and do everything from there (this is untested):

```
Protected Overrides Async Sub OnValidating(e As CancelEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnValidating(e)
    If SelectedIndex = -1 AndAlso Not (e.Cancel OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text)) Then
        DataSource = Await Task.Run(Function() GetMyDataSource(Text))
        DisplayMember = "display"
        ValueMember = "pessoa_id"
        If Items.Count > 1 Then
            e.Cancel = DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
            If e.Cancel Then
                DroppedDown = True
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Although, if possible, make `GetMyDataSource` `Async` as well (and return `Task(Of DataTable)`) so you can do:

```
DataSource = Await GetMyDataSource(Text)
```

Comment: What if I use a callback function instead of an event? Do you think it could work?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean, but give it a try. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

So based on [GabrielLuci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202807/gabriel-luci)'s insight, I decided `Async/Await` is not suitable for my needs, then I rolled back to good ole reliable BackgroundWorker logic and solved my problem:

```
Public NotInheritable Class QueryBoxEx

    Inherits ComboBox

    Private WithEvents Bg As New BackgroundWorker With {.Site = Me.Site}

    Public Property QueryCallback As Func(Of QueryData, Boolean)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnValidating(e As CancelEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnValidating(e)
        If Not e.Cancel Then
            If QueryCallback IsNot Nothing AndAlso SelectedIndex = -1 AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text) Then
                Dim qd As New QueryData With {
                    .DataSource = DataSource,
                    .DisplayMember = DisplayMember,
                    .Text = Text,
                    .ValueMember = ValueMember}
                Bg.RunWorkerAsync(qd)
            Else
                Dim dv = TryCast(MyBase.DataSource, DataView)
                If dv IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim rowfilter = ""
                    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DisplayMember) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text) Then
                        Dim xFilter = New Regex(MakePattern(Text), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                        Dim sFilter = DataSource.Select.Where(
                        Function(dr) xFilter.IsMatch(dr(DisplayMember).ToString)).Select(
                        Function(dr) String.Format("'{0}'", dr(DisplayMember))).ToArray
                        If sFilter.Any Then rowfilter = String.Format("{0} IN ({1})", DisplayMember, Join(sFilter, ","))
                    End If
                    dv.RowFilter = rowfilter
                End If
            End If
            e.Cancel = PostQueryCancelValidating()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function PostQueryCancelValidating() As Boolean
        If Items.Count > 1 Then
            DroppedDown = True
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            Return True
        ElseIf Items.Count = 1 Then
            SelectedItem = Items(0)
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Private Sub Bg_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Bg.DoWork
        If QueryCallback.Invoke(e.Argument) Then
            e.Result = e.Argument
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Bg_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles Bg.RunWorkerCompleted
        If e.Result IsNot Nothing Then
            With DirectCast(e.Result, QueryData)
                DisplayMember = .DisplayMember
                ValueMember = .ValueMember
                DataSource = .DataSource
                Text = .Text
                If PostQueryCancelValidating() Then
                    Me.Select()
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Class QueryData

        Public Property DataSource As DataTable

        Public Property DisplayMember As String

        Public Property Text As String

        Public Property ValueMember As String

    End Class

End Class
```

Usage (in Form class):

```
Private Sub Me_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    QueryBoxEx1.QueryCallback = AddressOf QueryBoxEx1_QueryCallback
End Sub

Private Function QueryBoxEx1_QueryCallback(e As QueryBox.QueryData) As Boolean
    Dim query = Utilities.Digits(e.Text)
    If query.Length > 7 Then
        e.DataSource = QueryFormat.CadastroIdentificador(sc, query)
        e.DisplayMember = "display"
        e.ValueMember = "pessoa_id"
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

It's working. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the `TPL` and `IProgress` instead? BackgroundWorker is quite old approach which creates threads (which can affect the performance)

Comment: @VMAtm, the reason is my lack of knowledge. Where can I find an example I can adapt to this scenario?